# Function returned undefined expecting Promise or value using async and await

Tags: typescript, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I have been using this code structure with httprequest cloud functions. It works well with those httprequest functions but now I get the "Function returned undefined expecting Promise or value" error using it with OnWrite function even if I return "Success!?".

Do you know where I am wrong? I am new to onWrite trigger and the whole cloud function world...

Here is my code:

```
export const toDashboardInfo = functions.firestore.document('maps/{mapId}').onWrite((change, context) => {  

  const doWork = async function()
  {
    //do stuff here with await
    return("Success!?");
  }

  doWork().then((returnData) => 
  {         
    return(returnData);
  }).catch((error) => { return(error)})

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a return:

```
return doWork().then((returnData) => 
  {         
    return(returnData);
  }).catch((error) => { return(error)})
```

Comment: Note however, that if it is technically valid to do `return returnData;`(see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?authuser=0) for some explanations) there is no interest to do that as it will not be considered by the Cloud Function (i.e. the Cloud function will not "treat" it, as it could be treated by an HTTPS Cloud function, e.g. sent back to the front end). So simply doing `return doWork().catch((error) => {console.log(error); return null;})` is equivalent.